# C# increment a variable and convert to string on one line

Tags: c#, string

Simple request -- does anybody know a way to consolidate this to one line:
*edit* - I was NOT confused about pre vs post increment operators.  The question I posted should have worked, I honestly do not know what happened.  somewhere between VS and SO I fixed it.

```
 startingMask++;
 string mask2 = startingMask.ToString().PadLeft(3, '0');
```

Something like

```
string mask2 = (startingMask++).ToString().PadLeft(3, '0');
```

*edit* -- Alright -- chill out  -- :)

Here is the final full solution, I should have provided more info in my first question, I was just looking for a nudge in the right direction (the number needed and starting number will be changing via a database pull at some point):

```
        int startingMask = 76;
        int numberNumberNeeded = 10;
        List<string> masks = new List<string>();

        while (numberNumberNeeded > 0)
        {
        string newMask = (startingMask++).ToString().PadLeft(3, '0');
            masks.Add(newMask);
            numberNumberNeeded--;
        }
```

Comment: but....... why?

Comment: Jamiec posted the right question: why would you do this? It just makes your code harder to read and to understand which is a bad thing. In particular in your case it won´t even cause *any* improvement.

Comment: I did a search and did not find a answer...I did not just throw it up there.

Comment: Sorry...I have to actually build a list with about 10 elements and was trying to avoid 20 lines of code.

Comment: Doing the same thing 10 times does not mean 10x{number of existing lines}. It's when you refactor your code to make it reusable, not try to squash "thing" into 1 line

Comment: "have to actually build a list with about 10 elements and was trying to avoid 20 lines of code" then you need a function that does it once and call it.  DRY

Comment: I still did not want the increment on its own line.  The solution is perfectly readable.  Why is it such a big deal that I want to do it inline vs having to do it before?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
string mask2 = (++startingMask).ToString().PadLeft(3, '0');
```

Postfix ++ `startingMask++` first take value and then increment value

Sufix ++ `++startingMask` first increment value and then take value

Comment: `(++startingMask).ToString("000")` would be even more compact

Comment: @DmitryEgorov -- Ideally constants should be used instead of hard-coded, "3", which would argue for the padleft but i'm being nitpicky